# XHR save document from within iframe with CSP protection

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, iframe, xmlhttprequest, content-security-policy

## The setup

We're running a spring boot project inside an iframe from another (spring boot) project. 
The top layer project holds an integrated view, and controls what program shows in the iframe. So far so good.

The top layer has CSP protection, so the only things we can show inside the iframe are trusted resources, they are the following:

```
"default-src 'self';" +
"style-src 'self';" +
"child-src 'self' " + getAllowedHosts() + " " + getDomain() + ";" +
"frame-src 'self' " + getAllowedHosts() + " " + getDomain() + ";" +
"img-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com;" +
"connect-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com " + getAllowedHosts() + ";" +
"font-src 'self';" +
"script-src 'self' www.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com;";
```

The project inside the iframe holds the following CSP settings:

```
"default-src 'self';" +
"style-src 'self';" +
"child-src 'self';" +
"frame-src 'self';" +
"img-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com;" +
"connect-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com;" +
"font-src 'self';" +
"object-src 'self' blob:;" +
"script-src 'self' www.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com;";
```

## The problem.

I'm trying to download a generated file (an excel file, although the type is irrelevant), with the following javascript code:

```js
/** 
 * @param url the url to post to
 * @param data formatted JSON string.
 */
 function download(url, data) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            var matches = /"([^"]*)"/.exec(disposition);
            var filename = (matches != null && matches[1] ? matches[1] : 'REI.xlsx');
            var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

            var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: type});
            if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                // IE workaround for "HTML7007:
                // One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created.
                // These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                return;
            }
            // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log(a.href);
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

When I open my page outside of the iframe'd environment, the file downloads just fine, but inside the iframe I get the following CSP error:

```
Chrome:
Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Firefox:
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob:https://localhost:8444/dd686147-ea7f-4711-86fd-715b4834e0ba (“default-src”).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I chose to do it via a dynamic form submit, with one input field, which holds the stringified JSON data.

The resulting download function :

```
/** 
 * @param url the url to post to
 * @param data formatted JSON string.
 */
function download(url, data) {
  var f = $('<form>')
    .prop('method', 'post')
    .prop('action', url)
    .css('display', 'none')
    .append($('<input type="text" name="data">').val(data));

  $('body').append(f);
  f.submit();
  f.remove();
}
```

This required me however to change the post on the server side as well, so it accepted a JSON String instead of a directly mapped POJO.